# Is this possible to change color of flowers dynamically using FLASH

Tags: flash

My problem is

I am creating a web app which contains a lot of flowers. One of the concept is to change the color of the flowers dynamically. All the flowers are IMAGES. Is there any possible way to do that in FLASH.

Is there any WEB SITE which currently have this functionality kindly provide the link it.

Thanks in Advance

Fero

Answer (score 1):

All the images in flash are objects of `Bitmap` class. The `Bitmap` class has a `bitmapData` property which in turn has `colorTransform` property. You can change the red, green and blue components of the image's color using the color transform class.

- [Bitmap](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Bitmap.html#bitmapData)
- [BitmapData](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#colorTransform())
- [ColorTransform](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html)

Answer (score 0):

or, you can create some masks in photoshop that only cover the flowers with different colors, and apply the masks with a blend mode. The colors will either merge or substract or whatever you choose.

Here's an example:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#blendMode